# Hi, I am not able to use Web3 and it's installed on my mac

Tags: web3js

I am not able to use Web3 and it's installed on my mac

npm install web3
up to date, audited 377 packages in 2s
57 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities

As you can see above, Web2 is installed but when i am trying to use the in HTML then it's throwing error:

HTML Code:

var web3 = new Web3();

Output:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined
 file:///Users/chetansharma/Documents/BlockChain/test.html:3

I request you to please help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the Web3.js library at the top of your file? You have to import the library to your javascript file before you can use it.

This changes depending on your environment, assuming you are using node.js you would want to include this:

`const Web3 = require('web3');`

Comment: It's installed on my Mac but when i am trying to use in HTML Frontend then it's showing error and due to that i am not able to continue my BlockChain Development, I request please help me to setup my BlockChain Development Environment, If this is not free then I will also pay.